# Record not getting on insert of a related record

Tags: apex, trigger

I have a Custom object called "Operational Event (OE)" in to which records are inserted from an external system. Our requirement is to create a Work Order out of an OE , if the created OE has a Start time Status as New and Asset Tag field's value should start with 3000.

I created a trigger to implement this requirement.

I tested it by inserting one OE record which is meeting my criteria and it worked. I tried to insert a bunch of records(all satisfying my criteria) using Data loader and there is no work order record created.

There is delimiter kind of logic i have in the code which will maximum create only 60 Work order records. To test this i tried to insert a bunch of records and nothing no work order got created.

I don't understand on what's going wrong.

The following is the code I have:

Apex trigger:

```
trigger OperationEventTrigger on sm1e__Operational_Event__c (after insert) {

    OperationEventHelper.CreateWorkOrder(Trigger.new);
}
```

Helper Class:

```
public class OperationEventHelper{

    public static void CreateWorkOrder(List<sm1e__Operational_Event__c> opEventList){
       Integer num = 0;
       sm1e__smWork_Order__c workOrder;
       Map<Id, sm1e__smEquipment__c> assetTagMap = new Map<Id, sm1e__smEquipment__c>();
       Map<Id, sm1e__smCObject_B__c> entitlementTermMap = new Map<Id, sm1e__smCObject_B__c>();
       List<sm1e__smWork_Order__c> workOrderList = new List<sm1e__smWork_Order__c>();

       Set<Id> assetTagIdSet = new Set<Id>();
       Set<Id> entitlementTermIdSet = new Set<Id>();

       List<RecordType> recordTypeList = new List<RecordType>();
       recordTypeList = [SELECT Id 
                         FROM RecordType 
                         WHERE DeveloperName = 'Work_Order'];

       for(sm1e__Operational_Event__c event : opEventList){
           assetTagIdSet.add(event.sm1e__Asset_Tag__c);
       }

       assetTagMap = new Map<Id, sm1e__smEquipment__c>([SELECT Id, 
                                                               Name,
                                                               Default_Failure_Class__c,
                                                               Default_Failure_Class__r.Name,
                                                               Entitlement_Term__c,
                                                               Entitlement_Term__r.Accept_AWO_S__c   
                                                        FROM sm1e__smEquipment__c 
                                                        WHERE Id IN: assetTagIdSet]);

       List<User> userList = new List<User>();
       userList = [SELECT Id,
                          Name 
                   FROM User 
                   WHERE Name = 'DG Monitoring'];                                                                                                       
       for(sm1e__Operational_Event__c event : opEventList){
           num = num + 1;
            if(num > 60)
               break;   
           if(event.sm1e__Status__c == 'New' &&
              event.sm1e__Start_Time__c != null &&             
              assetTagMap != null && 
              assetTagMap.containsKey(event.sm1e__Asset_Tag__c) && 
              assetTagMap.get(event.sm1e__Asset_Tag__c).Name.contains('3000.') && 
              assetTagMap.get(event.sm1e__Asset_Tag__c).Entitlement_Term__c != null &&
              assetTagMap.get(event.sm1e__Asset_Tag__c).Entitlement_Term__r.Accept_AWO_S__c && 
              (assetTagMap.get(event.sm1e__Asset_Tag__c).Default_Failure_Class__c != null && 
              (assetTagMap.get(event.sm1e__Asset_Tag__c).Default_Failure_Class__r.Name.equalsIgnoreCase('Plant Failures') 
              || assetTagMap.get(event.sm1e__Asset_Tag__c).Default_Failure_Class__r.Name.equalsIgnoreCase('Inverter Failures')))){
                 workOrder = new sm1e__smWork_Order__c();
                 workOrder.sm1e__WO_Type__c = 'Corrective';
                 workOrder.Event_Start__c = event.sm1e__Start_Time__c;
                 workOrder.sm1e__Equipment__c = event.sm1e__Asset_Tag__c;
                 if(assetTagMap.get(event.sm1e__Asset_Tag__c).Default_Failure_Class__r.Name.equalsIgnoreCase('Plant Failures'))
                    workOrder.sm1e__Description__c = 'Plant Forced Outage';
                 else
                    workOrder.sm1e__Description__c = 'Inverter Forced Outage';
                 workOrder.sm1e__Status__c = 'Ready to Schedule';
                 if(userList != null && !userList.isEmpty())
                    workOrder.sm1e__Assigned_To__c = userList.get(0).Id;       
                 workOrder.sm1e__Detailed_Comments__c = 'Investigate and schedule on-site resolution, as appropriate';
                 workOrder.Revenue_Category__c = 'Uncontracted CM';
                 workOrder.Billable__c = 'Billable';
                 workOrder.sm1e__Priority__c = 'High';
                 workOrder.sm1e__Failure_Code__c = 'Failure Class 1 - entire Plant off-line';
                 workOrder.Operational_Event__c = event.Id;

                 if(recordTypeList != null && !recordTypeList.isEmpty())
                    workOrder.RecordTypeId = recordTypeList.get(0).Id;

                 workOrderList.add(workOrder);

              }   
       }

       if(workOrderList != null && !workOrderList.isEmpty())
          insert workOrderList;
   }
}
```

Comment: Word to the wise, you can format your own code properly by selecting the code block and hitting the `{}` button. You can alternatively hit `CTRL + K` on Windows or `⌘ + K` on Mac.

Comment: Have you written a test class with bulk data. It is the best way to test